# How to email a file which resides in bamboo-artifacts after successful build of plan?

Tags: gradle, groovy, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I have a test-report file that resides in `bamboo-artifact` once the job is successfully executed. I want to email that report or file after successful execution. Is there any method I can include that file within a mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding artifacts in build notification mails is not possible in Bamboo.

So, You can either add this functionality (SMTP mail) in your code that will zip & mail the file

OR

You can customize the bamboo build notification by adding extra info [By Customizing the notification](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Add-artifacts-to-Bamboo-notifications/qaq-p/1104184) following this [Working with Freemarker](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/modifying-notification-templates-289276982.html?_ga=2.70874832.1517004761.1584859666-436347601.1582616345)